# How to call a python function in PySpark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a multiple files (CSV and XML) and I want to do some filters.
I defined a functoin doing all those filters, and I want to knwo how can I call it to be applicable for my CSV file?
PS: The type of my dataframe is: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're saying that you want to read in ONLY csv files? and not JSON files? You could loop over the directory for the CSV files alone and inside that loop do your filtering.

Comment: I already read the CSV file, I want to call my function to be applicable on it

Comment: You read in the CSV file as a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` yes?

Comment: yes with  spark.read.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you read in your first CSV files as `df1 = spark.read.csv(..)` and your second CSV file as `df2 = spark.read.csv(..)`

Wrap up all the multiple `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` that came from CSV files alone into a list..

`csvList = [df1, df2, ...]`

and then,

```
for i in csvList:
    YourFilterOperation(i)
```

Basically, for every `i` which is `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` that came from a CSV file stored in `csvList`, it should iterate one by one, go inside the loop and perform whatever filter operation that you've written.

Since you haven't provided any reproducible code, I can't see if this works on my Mac.

Comment: Is that will be working in spark cluster without calling a particular function from Spark?

Comment: No, you only need to wrap up all the `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` that you created from the CSV files into a separate list like I've written in the answer above, and then iterate through each of them, and perform whatever filter operation you want to perform.